# Dealing with single quotes in file paths as returned by find

Tags: bash, escaping, find

I am writing a bash script that, when run from directory `B`, mirrors the directory structure of directory `A` within directory `B`.

Currently, I am doing so as follows:

```
 #!/bin/bash          

 dirify () {
    echo $1
 }
 export -f dirify

 find "../test" -type d -exec bash -c "dirify '{}'" \;
```

I am running this script from directory `B`, and `../test` is directory `A`.
Fortunately, the directory I am using to test contains folders with `'` in the name. When I run this script, bash gives the following error when it reaches those directories:

```
> bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
> bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

(note that line 0 and line 1 refer to the lines within the `dirify()` function)

A more simplified way of illustrating this issue is as follows:

`find "../test" -exec bash -c "echo '{}'" \;`

This example produces the same errors.

Anyway, this is an issue because in production, I can't assume that file paths will not contain the `'` character.

Is there anyway around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as an argument.

```
bash -c 'dirify "$1"' dirify {}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Could you briefly explain how this syntax works?

Comment: When running a script via `-c`, bash takes additional arguments and assigns them starting from `$0`.